# need to display deeper item in ng-repeat AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Get an object from server. look like this:

```
"courses": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "piano",


        "classes": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "piano1",

          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "piano2",

          }
        ],
        "classes_count": 2,
        "feedbacks_count": 4
      },
]
```

JS: there I get data to Scope

```
httpService.getService(url, data).then(function(res) {
    $scope.datas = res.body.courses;
    console.log($scope.datas);
})
```

I need to print classes id in ng-repeat. try to do this

```
<ul  class="dropdown-list" style="display: none;">
    <li ng-repeat="course in datas | filter:{'id': showprofile}:true ">{{course.classes.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

But it's work when I print {{course.classes}} and I get an array with 2 objects. How to show in "li" element course.classes.id ?

Comment: you can change your `ng-repeat`. like `ng-repeat="classes in datas.course | filter:{'id': showprofile}:true "` and then use `{{classes.id}}`.

Comment: What are you getting now?

Comment: @Nitheesh not working

Answer (score 2):

You need to add another loop for nested elements

```
<ul  class="dropdown-list" style="display: none;">
   <li ng-repeat="course in datas" ng-if='$first'> {{course.id}}</li>//
      <ul ng-if="course.classes.length">
         <li ng-repeat="classes in course">     {{course.classes.id}}</li>
      </ul>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Get empty li element

Comment: <li ng-repeat="course in datas"> {{course.id}}</li> just show course id

Comment: Yes. If you need to show course Id along with class ID. You need this. And I have also added check for classes. If class exists than only second ng-repeat will execute.

Comment: How add my filter? I want show clasess from only first course

Comment: Do you You want to show  only first record and hide all other?

Answer (score 2):

You have array in array, so you have got 2 ng-repeats: first iterating over courses and second over classes.

```
<ul ng-repeat="course in datas" class="dropdown-list" style="display: none;">
     <li ng-repeat="class in course.classes">{{class.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Get empty li element